# Using Autofac's IIndex to resolve multiple Keyed instances

Tags: c#, autofac

I'd like to use AutoFac in a way that both a State and Strategy pattern coexist. After researching how, I got familiar with the Keyed/Named registration of Autofac and used this for my states using the passive `IIndex` method. After this, I was looking at the Strategy pattern, which to me looked like a good way of using the same idea, with resolving `IIndex` for both State and Strategy. I've saved my Strategy options in the same way (`enum`) as State and Keyed them in the `DependencyResolver`:

```
builder.RegisterType<NewAanvraag>().Keyed<IAanvraagState>(AanvraagState.Nieuw).Keyed<IAanvraagState>(BusinessState.Default);
builder.RegisterType<RareNewAanvraag>().Keyed<IAanvraagState>(AanvraagState.Nieuw).Keyed<IAanvraagState>(BusinessState.Rare);
builder.RegisterType<OpvoerenInformatie>().Keyed<IAanvraagState>(AanvraagState.OpvoerenInformatie).Keyed<IAanvraagState>(BusinessState.Default);
```

This way, I would like to use both options to be created in dynamic order, whereas some implementations might be the same as the default, and some are not.
However, when trying to access both the state and the strategy, I got a notion of `KeyedServiceIndex2 (DelegateActivator)`, but neither option could be resolved by itself

```
private readonly IIndex<AanvraagState, IAanvraagState> _states;
private readonly IIndex<BusinessState, IAanvraagState> _strategyState;

public IAanvraagDto AanvraagDto { get; set; }
private IAanvraagState CurrentState{ get { return _states[AanvraagDto.State];} }
private IAanvraagState CurrentStrategy { get { return _strategyState[AanvraagDto.BusinessState]; } }

public Aanvraag(IIndex<AanvraagState, IAanvraagState> states, IIndex<BusinessState, IAanvraagState> strategyState)
{
    _states = states;
    _strategyState = strategyState;
}

public void Start()
{
    CurrentStrategy.Start(AanvraagDto);
    SetState(AanvraagState.OpvoerenInformatie);
}
```

When I tried to use both it couldn't find the implementation (also tried `IIndex<BusinessState, IIndex<AanvraagState, IAanvraagState>>`):

```
private readonly IIndex<AanvraagState, IIndex<BusinessState, IAanvraagState>> _states;

public IAanvraagDto AanvraagDto { get; set; }
private IAanvraagState CurrentState { get { return _states[AanvraagDto.State][AanvraagDto.BusinessState]; } }

public Aanvraag(IIndex<AanvraagState, IIndex<BusinessState, IAanvraagState>> states)
{
    _states = states;
}

public void Start()
{
    CurrentState.Start(AanvraagDto);
    SetState(AanvraagState.OpvoerenInformatie);
}
```

Does anyone know how to use 2 Keyed variables to retrieve a grid-like structure for resolving the concrete implementation?

PS: This is the first question I ask on StackOverflow, so any constructive feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IIndex<K,V>` relationship is really just for single-dimension [keyed services](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). It won't work for multi-dimensional selection.

**What you're more likely looking for is [component metadata](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html)**, the ability to associate any arbitrary data with a registration and select the registration based on that data.

[The documentation has some great examples and details](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html), but I'll show you a simple example that might fit closely with what you're doing.

First, you need to define a metadata class. This is the thing that will track the various "dimensions" of the "matrix" by which you want to select your component. I'll do something simple here - two Boolean fields so there are only four total combinations of metadata available:

```
public class ServiceMetadata
{
    public bool ApplicationState { get; set; }
    public bool BusinessState { get; set; }
}
```

I'll use some very simple empty services just for illustration. Yours will obviously do something more. Note I have four services - one for each combination of metadata.

```
// Simple interface defining the "service."
public interface IService { }

// Four different services - one for each
// combination of application and business state
// (e.g., ApplicationState=true, BusinessState=false).
public class FirstService : IService { }
public class SecondService : IService { }
public class ThirdService : IService { }
public class FourthService : IService { }
```

Here's where you consume the services. To more easily take advantage of the strongly-typed metadata, you'll need to reference `System.ComponentModel.Composition` so you have access to `System.Lazy<T, TMetadata>`.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IService, ServiceMetadata>> _services;

    public Consumer(IEnumerable<Lazy<IService, ServiceMetadata>> services)
    {
        this._services = services;
    }

    public void DoWork(bool applicationState, bool businessState)
    {
        // Select the service using LINQ against the metadata.
        var service =
            this._services
                .First(s =>
                       s.Metadata.ApplicationState == applicationState &&
                       s.Metadata.BusinessState == businessState)
                .Value;

        // Do whatever work you need with the selected service.
        Console.WriteLine("Service = {0}", service.GetType());
    }
}
```

When you do your registrations, you'll need to register the metadata along with the components so they know which combination of data they belong to.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Consumer>();
builder.RegisterType<FirstService>()
    .As<IService>()
    .WithMetadata<ServiceMetadata>(m => {
        m.For(sm => sm.ApplicationState, false);
        m.For(sm => sm.BusinessState, false);
    });
builder.RegisterType<SecondService>()
    .As<IService>()
    .WithMetadata<ServiceMetadata>(m => {
        m.For(sm => sm.ApplicationState, false);
        m.For(sm => sm.BusinessState, true);
    });
builder.RegisterType<ThirdService>()
    .As<IService>()
    .WithMetadata<ServiceMetadata>(m => {
        m.For(sm => sm.ApplicationState, true);
        m.For(sm => sm.BusinessState, false);
    });
builder.RegisterType<FourthService>()
    .As<IService>()
    .WithMetadata<ServiceMetadata>(m => {
        m.For(sm => sm.ApplicationState, true);
        m.For(sm => sm.BusinessState, true);
    });
var container = builder.Build();
```

Finally, you can then use your consumer class to get services by "matrix," as you say. This code:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var consumer = scope.Resolve<Consumer>();
    consumer.DoWork(false, false);
    consumer.DoWork(false, true);
    consumer.DoWork(true, false);
    consumer.DoWork(true, true);
}
```

Will yield this on the console:

```
Service = FirstService
Service = SecondService
Service = ThirdService
Service = FourthService
```

**[Again, you'll definitely want to check out the documentation for additional details and examples.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html)** It will add clarification and help you understand other options you have available to maybe make this easier or work better in your system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer this question! I'm going to implement this option and provide the feedback here :)

Comment: Yes it did. I'm currently checking the registration process of the same thing in .Net Core using the json configuration file